# How can I disable the annoying change highlight in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable the annoying coloured bar in the gutter that shows me where a file has been changed. Shown below to the left of `"os"` and `"runtime/trace"`

[image]

Comment: in workspace settings, add "editor.codeLens": false

Answer (score 8):

Go File -> Settings -> User Settings -> 
and add this line

```
"git.enabled": false
```

Comment: Although this does indeed remove it, I want to preserve all other git functionality. I've raised an issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37975